# Cannot Install Ruby Gems 1.3.7 on Mac OSX 10.6.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I am following the instructions at http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard to install ruby 1.9.2 and rubygems 1.3.7

Everything goes smoothly until I get to the "Compile and Install RubyGems" part and enter the command line:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/ruby setup.rb
```

This continually returns the following error:

```
David-Issas-MacBook-Pro:rubygems-1.3.7 davidissa$ ruby setup.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.rb:5:in `require': no such file to load -- thread.so (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.rb:5
    from ./lib/rubygems.rb:11:in `require'
    from ./lib/rubygems.rb:11
    from setup.rb:24:in `require'
    from setup.rb:24
```

I received the same error when I was trying to setup ruby 1.8.7, as well.

Please Advise... I got ruby on rails up and running on a previous mac about 1 year ago, but I can't seem to repeat my previous success.

Thank You
David

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you use RVM instead, to manage your Ruby versions on the Mac: http://rvm.io/